# I am fairly new to neo4j and I have a dictionary of tuples as keys and some weight as values. I need to construct a a weighted graph with this data

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, cluster-analysis

The dictionary looks as shown below. While this is a small example, there is a combination of all the key pairs in the original data. I haven't show that here for convenience purposes.

```
{(319489, 385026): 25.444444444444446, (319489, 98313): 44.0, (319489, 188429): 35.44444444444444, (319489, 188432): 32.44444444444445, (319489, 352277): 0.0, (319489, 188439): 35.22222222222222, (319489, 352281): 0.0, (319489, 196634): 23.11111111111111, (319489, 352282): 0.0, (319489, 163869): 5.666666666666667, (319489, 196638): 35.0, (319489, 421717): 0, (319489, 188456): 24.88888888888889, (319489, 90154): 13.5, (319489, 196651): 34.333333333333336, (319489, 196652): 24.11111111111111, (319489, 65585): 11.666666666666666, (319489, 417843): 0.0, (319489, 188468): 37.22222222222222, (319489, 188475): 17.0, (319489, 196678): 14.0, (319489, 16458): 20.88888888888889, (319489, 196682): 17.555555555555557, (319489, 196684): 27.555555555555557, (319489, 417867): 23.666666666666668, (319489, 417868): 24.11111111111111, (319489, 196689): 32.66666666666667, (319489, 286805): 22.666666666666668, (319489, 32854): 22.777777777777775, (319489, 352347): 21.444444444444443, (319489, 352348): 20.88888888888889, (319489, 352349): 23.11111111111111, (319489, 352350): 24.666666666666668, (319489, 163935): 10.0, (319489, 352351): 24.11111111111111, (319489, 352352): 23.333333333333332, (319489, 352353): 24.777777777777775, (319489, 352354): 23.88888888888889, (319489, 352355): 23.0, (319489, 73831): 22.5, (319489, 196714): 27.222222222222225, (319489, 90224): 0.0, (319489, 196722): 37.55555555555556, (319489, 163955): 19.333333333333332, (319489, 196723): 28.444444444444446, (319489, 196726): 36.0, (319489, 24698): 0.0, (319489, 24699): 0.0, (319489, 114812): 9.666666666666666}
```

If there are ten values ranging from 1-10, the data has a combination of values as shown below:

```
{[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (8, 9), (8, 10), (9, 10)]}
```

This makes sure that there is a value associated to each node of an all to all graph without directions.

Now my problem is to represent this on neo4j or any graph structure in that case so that I can group the nodes that have the same weights.

Any help with representing this data as a graph on neoo4j would be helpful.

P.S. I'm using python to write code, it would be convenient if I can be directed towards a solution with connectors like the neo4j restclient so that I can build the graph while I loop over the data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.

It would be trivially easy to find the `Tuple` nodes with the same weight if each weight had a unique `Weight` node, and each `Weight` node was connected to every `Tuple` with the same weight. And, to avoid storing the same tuple values over and over again, you can also have unique `Key` nodes for each distinct value.

For example, for a subset of your data:

```
CREATE
  (k1:Key {value: 319489}), (k2:Key {value: 385026}),
  (k3:Key {value: 98313}),  (k4:Key {value: 188432}),
  (k5:Key {value: 188429}), (k6:Key {value: 352277}),
  (k7:Key {value: 188439}), (k8:Key {value: 352281}),
  (k9:Key {value: 196634}), (k10:Key {value: 352282}),
  (k11:Key {value: 163869}),

  (w1:Weight {value: 25.444444444444446}), 
  (w2:Weight {value: 44.0}), 
  (w3:Weight {value: 35.44444444444444}),
  (w4:Weight {value: 32.44444444444445}),
  (w5:Weight {value: 0.0}),
  (w6:Weight {value: 35.22222222222222}), 
  (w7:Weight {value: 23.11111111111111}), 
  (w8:Weight {value: 5.666666666666667}),

  (t1:Tuple {id: 1})-[:WEIGHT]->(w1),
  (t2:Tuple {id: 2})-[:WEIGHT]->(w2),
  (t3:Tuple {id: 3})-[:WEIGHT]->(w3),
  (t4:Tuple {id: 4})-[:WEIGHT]->(w4),
  (t5:Tuple {id: 5})-[:WEIGHT]->(w5),
  (t6:Tuple {id: 6})-[:WEIGHT]->(w6),
  (t7:Tuple {id: 7})-[:WEIGHT]->(w5),
  (t8:Tuple {id: 8})-[:WEIGHT]->(w7),
  (t9:Tuple {id: 9})-[:WEIGHT]->(w5),
  (t10:Tuple {id: 10})-[:WEIGHT]->(w8),

  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t1)-[:HIGH]->(k2),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t2)-[:HIGH]->(k3),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t3)-[:HIGH]->(k4),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t4)-[:HIGH]->(k5),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t5)-[:HIGH]->(k6),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t6)-[:HIGH]->(k7),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t7)-[:HIGH]->(k8),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t8)-[:HIGH]->(k9),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t9)-[:HIGH]->(k10),
  (k1)<-[:LOW]-(t10)-[:HIGH]->(k11)
```

To find all the `Tuple` nodes with the weight value `0.0`:

```
MATCH (w:Weight)<-[:WEIGHT]-(t)
WHERE w.value = 0.0
RETURN t;
```

To also get the tuple values:

```
MATCH (w:Weight)<-[:WEIGHT]-(t), (low)<-[:LOW]-(t)-[:HIGH]->(high)
WHERE w.value = 0.0
RETURN t, low, high;
```

To make the above queries more efficient, you should create an index on `:Weight(value)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Weight(value);
```

You will also need an index on `:Key(value)` when using `MERGE` to either reuse an exisiting `Key` or create a new one.